# Azure Media Service

Tags: azure-media-services

Requirement: Upload video(s) on Azure portal. Also generate streaming URL after video encoding.

Code was written in Java as per this page found on their website - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-java-how-to-use

but getting nothing in list when I try to retrieve list of AssetFileInfo
ListResult assetFiles = mediaService.list(AssetFile.list(asset.getAssetFilesLink()));

And due to this AssetFileInfo streamingAssetFile remains null and can't generate streaming URL as it is giving null pointer exception.

return originLocator.getPath() + streamingAssetFile.getName() + "/manifest";

Please assist. I am getting below error;
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.zensar.azure.storage.blob.migration.MediaServices.getStreamingOriginLocator(MediaServices.java:212)

Answer (score 0):

I just uploaded an mp4 file using the Azure portal. Then, I encoded the file and got the streaming URL as described in the article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-java-how-to-use).

The only change I made is commented out the following line:

//  AssetInfo uploadAsset = uploadFileAndCreateAsset("BigBuckBunny.mp4");

And used this instead:

ListResult outputAssets = mediaService.list(Asset.list());